# What is wrong with my thymeleaf html form here? Why is the Password showing value null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a basic form ,which takes in values from the user . The problem is all the html fields with type=text work fine and send the values to my java Back end API ,but only input type=password sends null value to the API.

MY HTML CODE :

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${register}" method="post">
            <input id="inputt" placeholder="First Name"  onclick="thisv1()" type="text" th:field="*{fname}" >
            <br>
            <input id="inputt1" placeholder="Last Name" onclick="thisv2()" type="text" th:field="*{lname}">
            <br>
            <input id="inputt2" placeholder="Email" onclick="thisv3()" type="text" th:field="*{email}">
            <br>
            <input id="inputt3" placeholder="Password" onclick="thisv4()" type="password" th:value="*{password}">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

My Spring Controller Code:

```
              @GetMapping("/register")
              public String form(Model model){
                  model.addAttribute("register",new Register());
                  return "register";
              }
              @PostMapping("/register")
              public  String SubmitForm(@ModelAttribute Register register){
                  DB.addValues(register.getFname(),register.getLname(),register.getEmail(),register.getPassword());
                  return "result";
              }
```

Register Class Code:

```
public class Register {
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String email;
private String password;
public void setFname(String fname){
    this.fname=fname;
}
public void setLname(String lname){
    this.lname=lname;
}
public void setEmail(String email){
    email=email.toString();
    this.email=email;
}
public void setPassword(String Password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getFname(){
    return fname;
}
public String getLname(){
    return lname;
}
public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}
public String getPassword(){
    return password;
}}
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably because `th:value` does not create the `name` attribute, as `th:field` does. The `name` attribute is required for mapping the values of the form fields to the correct setters of the form object. Try to explicitly add `name="password" ` to the input field. If it works, I'll write it as an answer

Comment: @qutax no its not working

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the resulting HTML? And maybe an example of the sent request (using the developer console of your browser)?

Answer (score 0):

Change your form field password declaration to this:

```
<input id="inputt3" placeholder="Password" onclick="thisv4()" type="password" th:field="*{password}">
```

You should map your thymeleaf input field to java object field. So, it should be th:field, instead of th:value.

th:value means actual value of input.

Ref: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes

Answer (score 0):

according to this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21920796/10822670
in thymeleaf you can not return value and put it into the password field.
it is ok if password is null. true is the user should not see the password.
usully problem is when you update user information. null password will insert into database.for prevent, you should put a filter before update data.
one of the solution is, you should use select first and get old user data from db and when condition if show null value you get the old password and insert into with new information.
how?
first download "apache beanutil" from site "mvnRepository.com" and put it on "pom.xml".

```
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
<version>1.9.4</version>
```

next creat a class and extends "BeanUtilsBean".

```
public class ApacheBeanUtils extends BeanUtilsBean{

@Override
public void copyProperty(Object bean, String name, Object value)
        throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    if(value == null || value.toString().isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Apache beanUtils");
        return;
    }
    super.copyProperty(bean, name, value);
}
```

}

now you can use this code in your service layer.

```
public Users updateUsers(Users users) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{
    if(users.getUsername() != null){
        Users exist = userRepository.findByid(users.getId());
        ApacheBeanUtils abu = new ApacheBeanUtils();
        abu.copyProperties(exist, users);
        return userRepository.save(exist);
    }
    return userRepository.save(users);
}
```

at the final,call **updateUsers** method on controller layer.
and your controller will be like:

```
@RequestMapping("/users/update")
public String updateUser(@ModelAttribute Users user) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{
    userService.updateUsers(user);
    return "redirect:/admin/users";
}
```

this library can replace the old data with new null data and insert into db.
be aware, we have two **copyProperties**in ApacheBeanUtils class must have three arguments and in updateuser method must have two arguments.
and null never inserted in database.hope it usefull.if it is usefull please rate the answer. thanks :)